# how to Zip folder Recursively in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am able to zip the folder but not in the recursive way.Please give me a solution??

Comment: What's your code look like to zip the single directory?

Answer (score 5):

As in java (it's the same)

```java
static public void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile)
        throws Exception {
    ZipOutputStream zip = null;
    FileOutputStream fileWriter = null;
    fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destZipFile);
    zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);
    addFolderToZip("", srcFolder, zip);
    zip.flush();
    zip.close();
}

static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
        ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception {
    File folder = new File(srcFile);
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
    } else {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            zip.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
}

static private void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder,
        ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception {
    File folder = new File(srcFolder);
    for (String fileName : folder.list()) {
        if (path.equals("")) {
            addFileToZip(folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName, zip);
        } else {
            addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/"
                + fileName, zip);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the first method (zipFolder) is the main method, others two, simply zip a single file (addFileToZip) or a folder (addFolderToZip).